# Drawing bare phrase structure trees with the forest package

Tags: forest, linguistics, trees

I need to emulate [these two trees](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vy9BI.jpg) and I've been trying different things but I can't get them exactly right. Every time I try the nice empty nodes option the tree ends up too elongated vertically, but I want it elongated horizontally.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: Post the complete minimal code for a tree with the vertical elongation and somebody will show you how to change it into horizontal elongation.